How can I wrap text in Flutter, breaking ONLY at spaces?
Currently the Flutter Text widget will break words in awkward places, such as breaking "Almacenamiento Digital" like:

The behaviour I want is for words that are too long for their container to not break at all, and if breaking is necessary for a string of multiple words, for it to only break the separate words to multiple lines only at spaces.
For our previous example, the word "Almacenamiento" is too long to fit in the container, so for my use case I want it to simply overflow. But the second word which would also expand beyond the container if remaining on the first line should in fact break to the next line because it is separated from the first word with a space.
Here is what I want:
Almacenamiento
Digital

And not:
Almacenamient
o Digital


https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text try this package

It seems that Almacenamiento does not fit in that first line with the formatting options that are in effect (which we can't see because you didn't share a minimal repro, so there's no way to make it fit the additional o in without changing the formatting options (i.e. picking a smaller font).

@FrankvanPuffelen If you read my description carefully you will see that I acknowledge that it does not fit, and I simply want the words to overflow. Picking a smaller font is not applicable to the real world use case of adapting to all possible translations in the world and testing them on every possible device.

@JBJason thank you for this. If I am unable to find a real solution then this fallback may be of great use.

If you want to prevent breaking the word on wrapping, just set the softWrap property of Text widget to false. And also if you want to make your words visible even though they overflow the boundaries, you can set the overflow property of Text widget to TextOverflow.visible.
If you want to wrap these words whenever, you don't have enough space, you can use this code:
SizedBox(
          width: 50,
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                child: Text(
                  'Almacenamient',
                  softWrap: false,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                ),
              ),
              Text('Digital')
            ],
          ),
        )

This code wont break any word and also show the overflow of the word and also wrap the second word to another line.
If you expect more, feel free to leave comment and I would be happy to share new codes.

Thank you, but what I want is for this to be done dynamically. I should have clarified that in my post. Otherwise yes, it is in fact trivial to place words exactly where I want them when they are defined this way.

@Derek Based on my current knowledge If you want to wrap the words without breaking any word, you should give enough width as long as the longest word. In your case if the width of the Text widget is set to be at least equal to "Almacenamiento" width, the "softWrap" property will manage the wrap correctly. If in some scenarios you give smaller space to your Text widget, I recommend using widgets like "FittedBox" to handle the text size dynamically.
